# Do I need a UK transit visa when going to Ireland from the US?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, paperwork

I am Egyptian; I have a valid US visa and I am travelling from the US to Dublin through London Heathrow. My layover is just 1:25 hours, and I need to change terminals (Terminal 3 to 2) at Heathrow, and I don't need to claim baggage.

My Irish visa is not BC/BC BIVS biometric endorsed. Do I need a UK transit visa?

Comment: @Newton Doesn't address his case very clearly. Adding an answer based on Timatic

Comment: What Irish visa do you have? A visit or residence visa, or a residence Permit Card?

Comment: i have an irish tourist visa

Comment: @Coke please add it here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25146/do-i-need-a-uk-transit-visa-when-flying-to-ireland-through-the-uk

Comment: @AliKourani See my answer here https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/106064/39782

Comment: can't reply to the other post. the website says that i need a standard visitor visa not a "visitor in transit". am i right ?

Comment: @AliKourani If travelling TO Ireland, not FROM. Select "somewhere else"

Comment: copied from Gov.uk: 
Travel to the Channel Islands, Isle of Man or Republic of Ireland
You need to apply for another type of visitor visa if you’ll be travelling to the Channel Islands, Isle of Man or Republic of Ireland.

You don’t need a UK visa if you have a valid visa for the Channel Islands or the Isle of Man and will travel through the UK to get there.

Comment: @AliKourani "You need to apply for another type of visitor visa if you’ll be travelling TO the Channel Islands, Isle of Man or Republic of Ireland". You're not travelling TO Ireland

Comment: @AliKourani This is the correct link. So I assure you 100% that you only need a visitor in transit visa https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/egypt/transit/somewhere_else/yes

Comment: @Coke i am sorry. i am confused. I am travelling to Dublin, republic of Ireland from Chicago

Comment: @AliKourani Oh crap, I read the question wrong. Will edit the answer

Comment: ok, thanks. now please check this: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/648410/UK_Visa_requirements_Oct_2017.pdf
will the US visa exclude me from applying to UK visa ?

Comment: @AliKourani A US visa only exempts you from having to apply for a "Direct Airport transit" or "Visitor in transit" visa, not a UK Standard visitor visa. Check my answer here - because your Irish visa in not biometric, you do need a Standard visitor visa. The answer explains why https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/106064/39782

Comment: @AliKourani In other words, if you only needed a transit visa, the US visa would've been enough. But you need a Standard Visitor visa, so the US visa won't help you in this case. That's why US visas aren't mentioned on the GOV.UK result page when Ireland is put as the destination